# about Grow along the path animation to unity!

Tags: animation, unity

I have an Grow along the path animation
My question is How do I export this animation to Unity via FBX?
I tried the bake animation but the result was wrong。
I do not want to use Amelbic

thank you !!!!
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question or tell us, what your problem is. What did you try to solve it already?

Comment: Most likely you need to change your bake settings. [Here is a tutorial](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/topic/271/) for doing this for Blend4Web - a different engine, but I imagine Unity expects the same kind of data.

Comment: @Mentalist Thank you very much, but it did not succeed

Comment: @Grimm  sorry My English is bad 。My question is How do I export this animation to Unity via FBX? I tried the bake animation but the result was wrong。I do not want to use Amelbic